# How To Apply A Font-Face Icon Into A Submit Button

Tags: css, font-face

i have the code for inputting font-face icons and it is working very properly but only into , ,

or  tags. when i try to use font-faces icons into form buttons (eg. image buttons, submit buttons, reset buttons...) it doesn't show.

hege goes the css code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("flaticon.eot");
    src: url("flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
    url("flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("flaticon.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {   
    font-family: Flaticon;
        font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
margin-left: 20px;
}.flaticon-delete13:before {
    content: "\e000";
}
```

and here goes the html snippet code that works fine:

```
<body>
    <div class="glyph-icon flaticon-delete13"></div>        
</body>
```

this is the link that goes into the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flaticon.css">
```

i want to put this font-face icon into a form button (eg. submit button) along with a text. for instance: an icon "cross" along with the text "Add".

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement font icon it is not possible with input tag.
Instead, use this for submit button:

```
<button class='button' type='submit'><span class="glyph-icon flaticon-delete13"></span>Submit</button>
```

Comment: great Effone! it works fine. just one more thing. i want to put this icon (only it) into a text field, right positioned, working as a clear field button. i can get it using an <a> tag but, <a> tags don't accept javascript functions. how can i have just the icon working as button so i can run javascript functions?

Comment: I'm unsure why you stated a tag doesn't accept javascript function. You can call js from a tag like this:  onclick="someFunction(arg); return false;"

Comment: could you please give me an example using <a href="#" class="flaticon-delete13"></a>?

Comment: this code worked perfect! thanks Effone for your assistance. i also thank the other 2 chaps for the help. i appreciate you pacience and help.

Comment: do you know any Javascript visual editor you can recomend me? any editor of WYSIWYG style. thanks.

Comment: Not any good one I know but you can have a glance at this: http://jsmaker.com/jsmaker/ though I don't recommend using one to improve your own skills only ...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Font Awesome to achieve this result.

Check out my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/irkanu/7VytQ/

I also used Bootstrap to achieve the minimal styling to the form.

The code for the button would be:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</button>
```

Comment: thanks Irkanu for the help. this button will be very usefull for my submit button. now, i want to transform the icon itself into a button, you see? i want to remove the icon from the square which is behind it and grant all the button behaviors to this icon. i want to use it inside a password field as a clear field for instance... or on the header menu. Effone said that i can use <a> tags (which i have the visual result that i want) for running javascript. could you show me how?

Comment: [Check out my new forked jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/irkanu/RX6g7/1/)Wrap the <i> tag with an anchor <a> add the onclick function within the anchor calling your javascript function.`<a href="#" onclick='clear_password()'><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>`

Comment: ok Irkanu, i'll do. that's exactly what i need. thanks again.

Comment: would u have in mind any visual javascript editor to recomend me? thanks.

Comment: I use Notepad++ as my editor then just run the code on your browser of choice. I use Google Chrome because I am familiar with the Right-click -> Inspect Element and it helps a ton!

Comment: thanks this is worked but one question after click add we want to have animation to add Datatables dot net for users to have more usability. animation like box that shows row info added to list

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for. You can use icomoon to create your own icons
http://jsfiddle.net/SKMN9/

```
   <button type="submit" class="buttons add">Add New Page</button>
```

Comment: thanks San for the help. this button will be very usefull for my submit button. now, i want to transform the icon itself into a button, you see? i want to remove the icon from the square which is behind it and grant all the button behaviors to this icon. i want to use it inside a password field as a clear field for instance... or on the header menu. Effone said that i can use <a> tags (which i have the visual result that i want) for running javascript. could you show me how?